# Chrome ignoring Watir goto request

Tags: watir-webdriver

I tried to use watir-webdriver with the chrome browser. While the browser pops up with "about:blank", it doesn't get the goto address. Works fine with FF.

```
$ gem list watir
commonwatir (4.0.0)
watir (5.0.0)
watir-webdriver (0.6.11)

Ruby version
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]

Chrome Version 39.0.2171.99 (64-bit)
```

And now the code itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "watir-webdriver"

b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto 'google.com'
b.close
```

Pointing out the obvious would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does Chrome do? Does it give an exception?

Comment: It does nothing. No exceptions. It's as if it doesn't receive the url.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the chromedriver was out of date. After downloading the latest version from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html, everything worked fine.